# How to access a DevExpress ASPx control via JSProperties on the client

Tags: javascript, asp.net, devexpress

Lets say that I have several DevExpress controls and one of them is a button. On that button I want to add the ClientInstanceNames of each of the other controls so that I can access them in the buttons client side click event..

c#:

```
String strID = "MyButton";
ASPxButton btn =  new ASPxButton() { ClientInstanceName = strID , Text = "Click Here", Width = new Unit("100%"), AutoPostBack = false, CssFilePath = strCssFilePath, CssPostfix = strCssPostFix };
btn.ClientSideEvents.Click = "btnClick";
btn.JSProperties.Add("cp_MyTxtBx", strID );
```

I want to do something similar to this...

js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function btnClick(s, e) {
            var theTxtBx = document.getElementById(s.cp_MyTxtBx);
            theTxtBx.SetText('some text');
        }
</script>
```

But that doesn't work.
I know that I could do it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function btnClick(s, e) {
            MyTxtBx.SetText('some text');
        }
</script>
```

But these controls are dynamically created and I will not know their ClientInstanceNames  until run time.

So, **how can I get the control based on the String JSProperty of its ClientInstanceName?**

Thanks in advance.

Related posts but not quite what I need:

[How to access the value of an ASPxTextBox from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200808/how-to-access-the-value-of-an-aspxtextbox-from-javascript)

[DevExpress: How do get an instance of a control client-side and access its client-side members?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7808230/devexpress-how-do-get-an-instance-of-a-control-client-side-and-access-its-clien)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understood you correctly this is what you need:

```
var theTxtBx = window[s.cp_MyTxtBx];
```

Every devex control with ClientInstanceName set is registered as global variable.

Comment: I actually already found this solution but I could not post an answer to my own question:
ASPxClientControl.GetControlCollection().GetByName(s.cp_MyTxtBx).SetText('heres my text')
But the window version seems better. Is one way better than the other?

Comment: I use my version extensively and everything works as expected. As you can see, it is considerably shorter.

Answer (score -1):

You could hack something...

Basically, as you dynamically create the textboxes give them a unique client instance name.

At then end of your page load, you can emit some javascript that declares and array and sets the elements to equal the textbox objects.

```
var ServerSideList = new List<string>();

while(CreatingTextBoxes)
{
    ...
    ServerSideList.Add(uniqueTextboxName);
}
....


var sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

sb.AppendLine("var clientSideList = [];");

foreach(var s in ServerSideList)
{
        sb.Append("clientSideList.push(");
        sb.Append(s);
        sb.AppendLine(");");
}

AspLiteralObject.Text = sb.ToString();
```

In the client side button click event, you could then iterate over the clientSideList array.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function btnClick(s, e) {
        var i;
        var theTxtBx;

        for(i = 0; i < clientSideList.length; i++)
        {
            theTxtBx = clientSideList[i];
            theTxtBx.SetText('some text');
        }
    }
</script>
```